# Kotlin: Create an array with inner-field of another array

Tags: kotlin

I was wondering if there was a shortcut to do that with Kotlin:

```
val userNames = ArrayList<String>()

for (user in users)
  userNames.add(user.name)

return userNames
```

That would be great if there was a one-line way to do this. Am I dreaming?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You're just performing a basic mapping operation. This is it:

```
users.map { it.name }
```

Comment: Any idea if there is an equivalent with Java 8? I could not find one :/

Comment: You couldn't find `Stream.map()`?